# How to get WordPress Time Zone setting?

Tags: php, date-time, options, timezones

Can someone tell me how to get the time zone that is set in the WordPress Admin?

For example, if the blog is set to Eastern time, I need this exact string to print out:

> US/Eastern

This is for a function that lives in functions.php in my theme.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

if you need the gmt_offset then

`<?php echo get_option('gmt_offset'); ?>`

this will give you an integer like **2 or -2**.

and if you need the timezone string use

`<?php echo get_option('timezone_string'); ?>`

this will give you a string like **America/Indianapolis**

Comment: My timezone_string is in the database but it is empty, even after selecting a different timezone on the settings page. What might be the case? (WP3.6)

Comment: Does gmt_offest take daylight savings into account based on the site's timezone setting?

Comment: @user2019515 If you choose a city as a timezone it will save to the "timezone_string" option but if you choose a Manual Offset (UTC+1 for instance) it is saved to the "gmt_offset" option (as "1") and timezone_string remains empty.

Answer (score 26):

The unfortunate situation is that there are indeed two different options:

1. Newer `timezone_string`, which saves PHP–style time zone.
2. Older `gmt_offset`, which saves numeric float offset in hours.

But in newer environments `timezone_string` actually *overrides* `gmt_offset`, the value returned by the latter will be based on the former. However the *opposite* isn't true — `gmt_offset` might be valid, while `timezone_string` is empty.

WordPress 5.3 had shipped [`wp_timezone()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone/) function, that abstracts this and returns a valid `DateTimeZone` object, regardless of underlying WP settings.

Before that I had a take on it implemented in my [`WpDateTime` library](https://github.com/Rarst/wpdatetime) (for trivia that was used as a basis for core implementation):

```
class WpDateTimeZone extends \DateTimeZone {
    /**
     * Determine time zone from WordPress options and return as object.
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function getWpTimezone() {
        $timezone_string = get_option( 'timezone_string' );
        if ( ! empty( $timezone_string ) ) {
            return new static( $timezone_string );
        }
        $offset  = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
        $hours   = (int) $offset;
        $minutes = abs( ( $offset - (int) $offset ) * 60 );
        $offset  = sprintf( '%+03d:%02d', $hours, $minutes );
        return new static( $offset );
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. People will run into bugs if they rely solely on get_option('timezone_string').

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: Isnt use of `(int)` for $hours and `floor` for $minutes problematic? According to documentation, `(int)` and `floor` are almost the same except `(int)` will round -4.5 to -4 and `floor` will round it to -5. This seems like it will give incorrect negative timezone offsets?

Comment: @Mikepote yeah, this was fixed in the lib a long time ago, just stale copy of the code in the answer here.

Comment: Oh my god why did they implement it like this .... It costed me a full hour *tilt*

Comment: Does the lib handle the fact that one timezone can contain multiple offsets? See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info

Comment: @DarkNeuron lib just leaves that to PHP, which includes and uses olson database.

Answer (score 9):

Check the [Option Reference page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Option_Reference). The option `gmt_offset` returns an integer. For example, if the timezone is set to Eastern time (e.g. America/New_York), `gmt_offset` should be -5.

Answer (score 3):

Given the fact that wordpress keeps the timezone string in the options table, you can use the object oriented way of getting the right time on your wordpress site:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone(get_option('timezone_string'));
$dt = new DateTime("now", $tz);

$page .= "<p> DateTime " . $dt->format("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't think you're gonna get a string like **US/Eastern** without storing all the strings you want in an array and referring to them. Using PHP you can get the timezone abbreviation, ie **EST**; and if you have those values stored in an array with the strings you want, you can look them up.

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set(get_option('timezone_string'));

      echo date('T'); // will give you three-character string like "EST"

      $timezones = array (
          'EST' => 'US/Eastern',
          'CST' => 'US/Central',
          // etc, etc, etc.
          );

      echo $timezones [ date('T') ]; // should be what you want.
 ?>
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. The [timezone standards](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) have been part of PHP since 5.2, as has the [DateTimeZone object](http://php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.getname.php) and the related standard functions.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Bainternet (I am adding this as an answer because I cannot comment  -- I have less than 50 points on WP Development stack).

WordPress will only store a timezone string if you select a timezone string in the general settings.  UTF selection is where it defaults in the list, but you can scroll way up to timezone strings.  If you set a timezone string, both the UTF and the Timezone string will be set.  They will be the same (meaning, the UTF gets reset to the new zone when you select a timezone string timezone).

(WordPress 4)

Answer (score 1):

[Like Rarst said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/283094/149131), you can now use [`wp_timezone()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone/) which returns a timezone object.

Or to get the timezone as a string, [`wp_timezone_string()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_timezone_string/), which returns 'Europe/Rome', 'UTC', or the UTC offset like '-6:00'.

And if you want the abbreviation, [`wp_date('T')`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_date/) also returns the localized timezone.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options, none of which really work great.  This is a WordPress bug, and it genuinely sucks because the time is wrong unless you set your site to UTC... which is confusing and not always even possible.

This next code I think only works if you choose your Timezone (Under Settings -> General in admin) as a named city instead of by an GMT number offset.  I haven't tested this but it's very possible that `get_option('gmt_offset')` is set when `get_option('timezone_string')` is not.

```
date_default_timezone_set(get_option('timezone_string'));
```

The downside of this is that WordPress assumes PHP is set to UTC when making mysql timestamps, so you can mess up your database a little bit whenever you switch timezones!  Not to mention other WP plugins may assume that the PHP environment is always in UTC.

So, if you just want a correct time -- you can force your timestamp to be in UTC with:

```
get_post_time('c', true); //should work for non-post objects.
```

Unfortunately, although correct, it'll make the timezone get set to UTC.

And note that you can't **both** use the "true" flag **and** the default timezone_set function.

Any *proper* solution is gonna be a code-snippet that accounts for both `gmt_offset` AND `timezone_string` and uses them to set a timezone on some input.  WP assumes that PHP set to UTC when doing mysql timestamps, and it might break other plugins.

There's one such solution on https://www.skyverge.com/blog/down-the-rabbit-hole-wordpress-and-timezones/ but, again this is a BUG, so you should use the `get_post_time($date_format, TRUE)` code to get a timestamp that is actually correct.