# Wordpress time queries

Tags: php, timezones

When we setup the timezone in wordpress settings page. Does it changes the server time? If I call `time();` does it returns unix time according to timezone setup in the settings page?

I have checked this page here [How to get WordPress Time Zone setting?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/how-to-get-wordpress-time-zone-setting)

So, if i need to show suppose the current time of a neighborhood site what modification i have to do with the output of `time();` function? The php `time();` returns the time in the server. So is that depends on where my host belongs?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress tries to set PHP environment to UTC timezone. Usually it is more reliable to use time zone-aware WP functions, such as [`current_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time), rather than vanilla PHP functionality.