# Default Timezone setting in WordPress - is that global?

Tags: date-time, timezones

Despite the WordPress Options' Timezone setting for the whole WordPress installation, **is it necessary to declare the default timezone in all the date/time places in a WP theme/plugins?**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
echo date('d M Y - D - h:i A');
```

Suppose I'm handling with something where I'm checking whether the date&time is equals to ***TODAY***. You know what "Today" means is a bit variable - variable to server time, variable to local time etc.

That's why I'm looking for a standard procedure to follow in WP projects, whether to set the default timezone each and every time (or [do I call them](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8404/22728) always in the header?) or to avoid them as WordPress itself declared that already (just tune that before).

I'm just looking for a standard procedure - what to follow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the safest way to handle it is to use the API to get the local time as set in WordPress settings-

```
$today = date( 'd M Y - D - h:i A', current_time( 'timestamp' ) );
```

EDIT- apparently [`current_time`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_time) also accepts a PHP date string now as of version 3.9, so you can use that directly in place of `date`.