# How to convert DateTime() to display time based on WordPress timezone setting?

Tags: date-time, timezones

I need to use PHP's `DateTime()`. It's currently displaying GMT time instead of the time that's set for the timezone setting (EST) in the WordPress Admin.

How can this be converted to show the the time base

```
$time = new DateTime();
echo $time->format("Y-m-d h:i:s");

// 2015-08-12 04:35:34 (gmt)
// 2015-08-12 12:35:34 (what i want -- EST)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure why EliasNS' answer is marked correct, as far as I'm aware (and from the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)), the second parameter of `DateTime::__construct()`, if provided, should be a `DateTimeZone` instance.

The problem then becomes, how we do we create a `DateTimeZone` instance. This is easy if the user has selected a city as their timezone, but we can work around it if they have set an offset by using the (deprecated) Etc/GMT timezones.

```
/**
 *  Returns the blog timezone
 *
 * Gets timezone settings from the db. If a timezone identifier is used just turns
 * it into a DateTimeZone. If an offset is used, it tries to find a suitable timezone.
 * If all else fails it uses UTC.
 *
 * @return DateTimeZone The blog timezone
 */
function wpse198435_get_blog_timezone() {
    
    $tzstring = get_option( 'timezone_string' );
    $offset   = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
        
    //Manual offset...
    //@see http://us.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php
    //@see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45543
    //@see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45528
    //IANA timezone database that provides PHP's timezone support uses POSIX (i.e. reversed) style signs
    if( empty( $tzstring ) && 0 != $offset && floor( $offset ) == $offset ){
        $offset_st = $offset > 0 ? "-$offset" : '+'.absint( $offset );
        $tzstring  = 'Etc/GMT'.$offset_st;
    }

    //Issue with the timezone selected, set to 'UTC'
    if( empty( $tzstring ) ){
        $tzstring = 'UTC';
    }

    $timezone = new DateTimeZone( $tzstring );
    return $timezone; 
}
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
$time = new DateTime( null, wpse198435_get_blog_timezone() );
```

Comment: This will not correctly handle half-hour timezones, `Etc/*` are recommended to not be used in general.

Comment: Yes - hence 'deprecated' :). I'm not aware of a better way of handling half-hour off-set timezones. Seems the best solution is to encourage adoption of a city as timezone identifier or avoid DateTimeZone in a WordPress context.

Comment: I added the answer with my take from my `WpDateTime` lib. :)

Answer (score 3):

I had developed a method in my lib to retrieve current WP’s time zone as proper object: [`WpDateTimeZone::getWpTimezone()`](https://github.com/Rarst/wpdatetime/blob/master/src/WpDateTimeZone.php).

While `timezone_string` is straightforward (it is already a valid time zone name), `gmt_offset` case is nasty. Best I could come up with is converting it into a `+00:00` format:

```
$offset  = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
$hours   = (int) $offset;
$minutes = ( $offset - floor( $offset ) ) * 60;
$offset  = sprintf( '%+03d:%02d', $hours, $minutes )
```

Comment: Requires PHP 5.5 (* ducks *). As @rarst pointed out in his comment on my answer using `Etc/*` is not recommended, going forward this is the way forward to handle offsets.

Comment: _Requires PHP 5.5_ — you say it like it’s a problem... :)

Answer (score -1):

`DateTime` aceppts a `DateTimeZone` parameter, that you can get from WordPress options. Something like:

```
$time = new DateTime(NULL, get_option('gmt_offset'));
```

- [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)
- [WordPress TimeZone](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/how-to-get-wordpress-time-zone-setting)

Hope this helps.

Edit: I'm testing it and I get an error. I don't know how to convert the `timezone string` to a `DateTimeZone` object, but that is the way.

Comment: Both options return a string. Now we need to create an `DateTimeZone` object from it. I can't help more :(