# A non-numeric value encountered in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 68

Tags: php, functions, errors

We recently updated our shared hosting to use PHP 7.3 (problem still existed in PHP 7.2 as well) - website is throwing the error in the title.

the function in question is:

```
function current_time( $type, $gmt = 0 ) {
switch ( $type ) {
    case 'mysql':
        return ( $gmt ) ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) : gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) ) );
    case 'timestamp':
        return ( $gmt ) ? time() : time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS );
    default:
        return ( $gmt ) ? gmdate( $type ) : gmdate( $type, time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) );
}}
```

Line 68 is:

```
return ( $gmt ) ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) : gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + ( get_option( 'gmt_offset' ) * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) ) );
```

The functions file has not been modified - any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Try to re-save the "General" settings - make sure a proper *timezone* is selected. If that doesn't help, then the `HOUR_IN_SECONDS` constant is probably not a numeric..

Comment: Really? Wow! That was it. I simply needed to reselect my time and date options in general settings and save. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

There is [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/8400/how-to-get-wordpress-time-zone-setting#answer-283094) dealing with a slightly more complicated issue than yours, but it contains a lesson.

Basically, what I learned is that you should process your equation in two or more steps, to account for gmt_offset being returned as a string:

```
$offset  = get_option( 'gmt_offset' );
$hours   = (int) $offset;

return ( $gmt ) ? gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ) : gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', ( time() + ( $hours * HOUR_IN_SECONDS ) ) );
```

This should avoid the error you are seeing.

Good luck!

Comment: The function in the question is a core function. They can't modify it.